# Upgrade Ruby on Rails from 2.x.x to 3.x.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I'm using ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.1.1. Now I'm working in a project with Rails 2.3.8 and want to upgrade it to Rails 3. So can I do this in my computer(ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.1.1)? I followed this [tutorial](http://blog.siyelo.com/rails-3-upgrade-process-the-road-from-2-3-14-to-3-2-6/) but when I used `gem install rails` it seemed that rails 2 upgraded directly to rails 4.1.1 (current version). Can someone explain clearly to me and tell me the best choice to do in this circumstance?

Comment: Are you using [`rvm`](http://rvm.io)? If you do `gem install xyz` it will try to install the latest `xyz`. You can specify the version you want to install on the `gem` command line, *e.g.*, `gem install rails -v 3.0`. But if you are trying to manage multiple projects potentially with different versions, you want to use something like `rvm`.

Comment: @lurker I used rbenv, if I intall -v 3.0(in rails 2.x project directory) will it affect to the rails 4.1.1 in my computer?

Comment: @hoamaudon no. satisfied.